# Adding a dictionary to a list python - ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python

I keep getting a "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required" when i try to post a new comment into the comments list

```
# import the Flask class from the flask module
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

# create the application object
app = Flask(__name__)

posts=[]

@app.route('/index')
def index():
user = {'nickname': 'Miguel'}
posts = [
    {'author': {'nickname': 'John'}, 'body': 'Beautiful day in Portland!'},
    {'author': {'nickname': 'Susan'}, 'body': 'The Avengers movie was so 
cool!'}
]
return render_template("index.html", title='Home', user=user, posts=posts)

@app.route('/postAnonComment', methods=['POST'])
def SaveDetails():
userName = request.form['user_name']
userMail = request.form['user_mail']
userMessage = request.form['user_message']

newDictionaryItem = newDictionaryItem = "{'author': {'nickname': '{}'}, 
'body': '{}'}".format(userName, userMessage)
posts.append(dict(newDictionaryItem))

return render_template('index.html', user=userName, posts=posts)

# start the server with the 'run()' method
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: please post your complete error traceback

Comment: Please fix your indentation!

Comment: Apologies, it is indented correctly in my IDE

Comment: Can't you do this `newDictionaryItem = {'author': {'nickname': userName}, 'body': userMessage}` instead?

Comment: @Dylan: If you want us to help you finding an error you cannot find it is mandatory that you do the indentations exactly as in your code. It should not be a problem: just paste our code and then select the code and mark it as code. You can edit your post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to do it they way you used `dict` via a string but you could:

```
posts.append(dict(eval(newDictionaryItem)))
```

Better would be to just use a normal `dict` assignment:

```
newDictionaryItem = {'author': {'nickname': userName}, 'body': userMessage}
posts.append(newDictionaryItem)
```

Comment: There's no need to call `dict()` on a `dict`

Comment: @MatiasCicero: You are, of course, right. Thanks for correction. I have corrected the post.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create a `dict` from a `str`:

```
newDictionaryItem = """{'author': {'nickname': '%s'}, 'body': '%s'}""" % (userName, userMessage)
posts.append(dict(newDictionaryItem))
             ^^^^^
```

Python will not do this parsing for you. To fix this, create the dictionary manually:

```
newDictionaryItem = {'author': {'nickname': userName }, 'body': userMessage }
posts.append(newDictionaryItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a string representation of `dict` and trying to make `dict` out of it is inefficient, when you can directly do it.

```
newDictionaryItem = {
    'author': {'nickname': userName},
    'body': userMessage,
}
posts.append(newDictionaryItem)
```